# How can I ping a VM on a hypervisor from outside the host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hypervisor

I have a CentOS 7 hypervisor running. The hypervisor IP is 192.168.195.10, and I created a VM with the IP address of 192.168.122.136 and the gateway of 192.168.122.1.

I can ping from hypervisor to the VM.

When I try to connect other computers to the network I can ping from it to the hypervisor, but I cannot get to the VM and not to the gateway of the VM.

- Host to VM: Good
- Outside to Host: Good
- Outside to VM: No Good

Can someone give me direction to solve this issue?

Comment: How is the VM connected to the network? The choices are typically: Bridged, NAT, Host-only. Bridged uses your hosts network connection. And host-only is restricted to the host. NAT will get an IP address from your network’s router. How to solve this issue depends on the software you are using for your Hypervisor.

Comment: I used NAT, I want this VM to have access to outside world as well

Comment: Well, what you are asking is basically how to network from your router to the VM and that is a very common request. Will find a post that covers that.

Comment: Thanks very much Glacomo, ill inspect this post

Comment: Happy to help! But remember: Not every post and bit of advice will be 100% a good fit for your needs. Just remember the core of what you want to do: Access your VM from the outside world. In general the concept is called “port forwarding” and if you can forward a port on your router to a port on your host machine and the VM then you are solid.

Comment: Thank you very much